# Need to print every line in a file one by one using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `output.txt` has the below contents

```
state online
progress 55
time 21/01/2019
type master
disk_count 55
disk_type medium
```

and goes on for 100 lines with space separated.

I have tried:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in (output.txt) do ( set z=%%i goto print )
:print
echo %z%
for /f "skip=1' %%g in (output.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%g"
echo %line%
```

I would need to print out each and every line one by one.
 sometimes the character next to the space is omitted if i try to print.

Can you please help with a batch file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I make out what you're saying, you want this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (output.txt) do echo %%i
```

As per your comment, doing a line by line we need to exit the loop until you decide to enter it again:

```
@echo off
set /a cnt=0
:begin
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type output.txt ^| more +%cnt%') do echo %%i & goto continue

:continue
set /a cnt+=1
pause>nul
goto begin
```

Alternatively you need to tell the scipt yourself which line to goto:

```
@echo off
:begin
set /p cnt=Enter the line number to print (1,2,3,etc):
set /a cnt-=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type output.txt ^| more +%cnt%') do echo %%i & goto continue

:continue
set /a cnt+=1
echo Press any key to display the next line.
pause>nul
goto begin
```

You will note that first we set the variable `%cnt%` and then we deduct 1 again, that is because of the `more +N` command. If you want to display line one, it means we do not want to skip any line, therefore you select `1` and we deduct one, meaning we skip `0` lines and it will print line `1` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I need to print only one line at one time and another one the next time. 
For some part of the script, i need to display only 2 nd line as output and then in later part of the script,
i need to print only 4 th line as output. so i tried to print a single line using for loop repeatedly.

@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in (output.txt) do ( set z=%%i goto print )
:print echo %z%

for /f "skip=1' %%g in (output.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%g"
echo %line%

The first for loop prints first line correctly. But second for loop is not printing correctly.

Comment: @PrasannaRam but you cannot do that selectively. the only way is to pre-inform the script how many lines to skip. Let me update the answer and show you more or less

Comment: Thanks a lot, i managed to print line by line.

My file has the below.

type master
disk_count 55
disk_type medium
vdisk_UID 767678687687987D888080980980809
type master
disk_count 56
disk_type fast

When i try to print the 4 th line using the below 

for /F "skip=3 delims=vdisk_UID" %%i in (opt.txt) do (  
  set Z=%%i
  goto BREAK
)
:BREAK
echo vdisk_UID=%Z%

I get the output as 
vdisk_UID= 767678687687987
It prints only until it finds a alphabet in it and skips rest. Can you guide to print the whole text next to
vdisk_UID